# Where can I find a snort signature for detecting slowhttp DoS attack from Slowloris tool

Tags: ids, denial-of-service, snort

I am performing a test on some DoS attacks and how to detect them. I am currently testing the slowloris tool, but all the signature I have seen online, as very very few as they are,do not work even after modifying some parameters. Can someone point me to a site or an example of the snort detection rule for detecting slowloris attacks.

Comment: And the only answer to the latter correctly mentions that "it goes outside of the normal bounds of what Snort is designed to detect".

Comment: @Ximaera when deciding what is a duplicate, don't you look at the time stamp? This question was asked in April 2017. While the one you referenced was asked in November 2017... So which one is a duplicate of the other ?

Comment: But that question got a proper answer. I thought it's a good idea to reference it. Is it against the community rules here? Please advise.

Comment: Yeah @ximaera you are right. The question can be marked as duplicate if there exits another question with a good enough answer. See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). I have gone ahead and accepted it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

slowloris don't finish web request header.

`pcre:!"/\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0A$/H";` will detect web request not ending with `0D0A0D0A`

Or you can also use `/D` that Match unnormalized HTTP request or HTTP response header.

But i'm not sure this would work.:) In fact, i think it is better to monitor changes in session volume than pattern matching, if you want to detect like slowloris.

Comment: Are you sure this would work? `/H` matches the normalized HTTP header but since slowloris does send the pieces of the HTTP header slowly there will be no HTTP header to normalize and thus I would expect that this rule does not get executed at all. Apart from that I would expected the *normalized* header to contain `\r\n\r\n` because it is normalized.

Comment: yeah @SteffenUllrich these are some of the complicated things about detecting this attack. Anomaly based IDS's do actual detect this attack, but I wanted to see how effective an open source IDS like snort is to detecting slowloris and so far, non of the signatures I have seen works. I want to be sure I exhaust all expert opinion on this before I draw my conclusion that snort if ineffective on detecting slowloris

Comment: I edited my answer.